# Data inconsistency between coredata entity attributes in app and fetchresults query in app share extension

Tags: core-data, viewcontext

Am using coredata in my app as well as its share extension (by leveraging app groups).

Step 1. User saves data in the core app (in the standard viewContext), and then loads the share extension that connects to core data (also standard videContext) and displays the entity and its attributes. This works fine so far.

Step 2. User dismisses the share extension screen without making any changes, goes back and changes the entity in the core app, then brings up the share extension sheet again, this time the data shown in the share extension is stale (shows what was showing in step 1)

Closing safari (app that share extension is launched from) and reopening it shows the correct refreshed attributes.

Ive ruled out the issue being in the UI layer (by printing the attribute values to the console after fetch). The issue is the share extension fetchrequest is returning stale values.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the shareExtensions viewContext to complete clear its cache solves this issue